# multi process Daphne with supervisor, getting [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: django, supervisord, channel, daphne

daphne and Django channels work fine on command line or single process. But when I start it with supervisor, the error occurs.

`2020-02-18 12:40:35,995 CRITICAL Listen failure: [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket`

My config file is

```
[program:asgi]

socket=tcp://localhost:9000

directory=/root/test/test/

command=daphne -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --endpoint fd:fileno=0 --access-log - --proxy-headers test.asgi:application

# Number of processes to startup, roughly the number of CPUs you have
numprocs=2

# Give each process a unique name so they can be told apart
process_name=asgi%(process_num)d

# Automatically start and recover processes
autostart=true
autorestart=true

# Choose where you want your log to go
stdout_logfile=/root/test/test/script/asgi.log
redirect_stderr=true

[supervisord]
[supervisorctl]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There seemed to be a bug with either Python or Twisted unable to bind to the file descriptor 0 as referenced here: https://github.com/django/daphne/issues/263

Try to bind the socket to another fd, say 10 like so:
`daphne -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd 10 --access-log - --proxy-headers test.asgi:application`

If that doesn't work, try checking whether you have read and write access to the /run/daphne/ folder itself

Comment: I am getting the same issues. I also tried with other values except 0 but still issue remains. Daphne works fine without using the --fd option. Is that recommended in production with multiple processes spawned by supervisor?

Comment: I don't think that's recommended. 
What is interesting though, when I tried after restarting the server, setting the fd to 0 works.

Answer (score 1):

First line - [program:asgi]

Must be like this: [**fcgi-program**:asgi]

If you carefully study the documentation, it is obvious that the first line of the config is incorrect.

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html#example-setups

Look carefully at the given config in the example`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.